# How can I disable vs code editor's feature that auto-orders rows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, text-editor

I'm developing a C++ derived class using Visual Studio Code (version 1.37.0) on Windows.

In the derived class, I copy pasted the alias members of the base class, and then I meant to rearrange them with *typename Base::*. If I paste that piece of expression, the editor reorders the various using-instructions alphabetically, not letting me finish to paste in all rows.

I'd like to disable this feature, but I couldn't find out how to do it. I tried searching the web and in the settings of VS Code, but I actually didn't find anything that could be related to my problem.

The extensions I've installed are *C/C++* and *Bookmarks*.

I'm using the Webkit coding style (set from the settings) with no additional *.clang-format* file.

In the *c_cpp_properties.json* file I set intellisense mode to *gcc-x64*, since I'm using g++ compiler.

I have also enabled the *format on paste* feature (which is why it formats the code after I paste, of course).

This is the situation after the first copy-paste (I also deleted the assignment parts).

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    using i = int;
    using f = float;
    using c = char;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    using i;
    using f;
    using c;
};
```

If now I paste *typename Base::* before *i* (the first alias), the three lines are reordered as follows:

```
    using c;
    using f;
    using typename Base::i;
```

And so on with the others.

This is just a simple example.
I know that it's a good habit to keep an order (alphabetical ordering is quite common, I think), but I got several reasons why I shouldn't keep it in this case.
Anyway, I'd like to manually decide the ordering and not let the editor do it for me, also because it confuses me while reading/writing.

Hope you know or can find a way to solve my problem,
thanks in advance.

Comment: Use this to generate your own rules and turn off the bits you don't want https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/

Comment: You should be able to avoid the reordering by inserting blank lines between them